# Closing programs with a script

Tags: windows

I have a script which when clicked, starts a variety of programs and documents related to a specific task. These include a PDF file, a spreadsheet, 4 browser sites, AIM, 3 programs and 2 Word documents. Very straightforward and never fails to work but my question is, can I make a script for Windows 7 that closes all of these down when I'm done with them? Yeah I know it will only save me 30 seconds but hey, I'm geekish :)

Comment: Have a look at the windows `TASKKILL` command. http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html

Comment: The odd thing here is that Taskkill works for Notepad, but does not work for aim, or for macro express, or any other running program. I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's OK I've got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TASKKILL command is the solution for your problem. You need windowtitle or pid of the tasks you created to kill the right processes. You can also use wildcards, if you know when to use it. Use TASKLIST to view the list of currently running process.